# Laravel 5 how to set Cache-Control HTTP header globally?

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, http-headers

My Laravel application is returning `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` HTTP header by default for each site. How can I change this behaviour?

P.S.: It is not a PHP.ini problem, because changing `session.cache_limiter` to empty/public does not change anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Laravel 5.5 <

You can have a global middleware for that. something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CacheControl
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');
        // Or whatever you want it to be:
        // $response->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=100');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

then just register this as a global middleware in the Kernel file:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ....
    \App\Http\Middleware\CacheControl::class
];
```

Answer (score 27):

## Laravel 5.6+

There's no longer any need to add your own custom middleware.

The `SetCacheHeaders` middleware comes out of the box with Laravel, aliased as `cache.headers`

The nice thing about this Middleware is that it only applies to `GET` and `HEAD` requests - it will not cache `POST` or `PUT` requests since you almost never want to do that.

You can apply this globally easily by updating your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->middleware('cache.headers:private;max_age=3600') // added this line
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}

protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->middleware('cache.headers:private;max_age=3600') // added this line
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

I don't recommend that though. Instead, as with any middleware, you can easily apply to specific endpoints, groups, or within the controller itself, e.g.:

```php
Route::middleware('cache.headers:private;max_age=3600')->group(function() {
    Route::get('cache-for-an-hour', 'MyController@cachedMethod');
    Route::get('another-route', 'MyController@alsoCached');
    Route::get('third-route', 'MyController@alsoAlsoCached');
});
```

Note that the options are separated by **semicolon** not comma, and hyphens are replaced by underscores. Also, Symfony only supports [a limited number of options](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6c3390a231b920637e5dc9301bd3ce3e7e5293fc/Response.php#L935):

`'etag', 'last_modified', 'max_age', 's_maxage', 'private', 'public', 'immutable'`

In other words you can't simply copy and paste a standard `Cache-Control` header value, you will need to update the formatting:

```
CacheControl format:       private, no-cache, max-age=3600
  ->
Laravel/Symfony format:    private;max_age=3600
```

Comment: For some reason, this solution broke my login system. I'm still not sure why. I used your solution (for Laravel 5.5 <) and it worked instead. :) Note that I am using Laravel 6.2.

Comment: @AlmostPitt.. This happened to me as well. I think Sympony does not support this. They have updated recently.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35720

Comment: I know it's also possible to do things in the routes file.  Is it possible at a group level for a bunch of different routes ?

Comment: @AdamJones yes that’s the `Route::middleware` example I give. I only have 1 route listed there but it’s within a group and you could add more

Comment: Hi @andrewtweber thanks for the response but I really am after doing it for some specific routes from within the /routes/web.php file.   Do you have an example of how a Route::group definition can have headers defined within it?

Comment: @AdamJones I updated the example, is that more clear? You just chain the middleware before the `group()` call

Comment: @andrewtweber... my route group is defined as follows: Route::middleware(['forAccountHoldersAjaxOnly'])->group( function() {

How do I add a header to that to stop all caching?  I'm not 100% sure of syntax and can't find it explained anywhere on the web.

Comment: this is effected $request->session()->put('')

Answer (score 5):

For people that seek a way to write less code, here is another way you can add headers to a response without extra steps.

In the example above, I created a middleware to prevent routes from being cached in the end user browser.

```php
<?php

class DisableRouteCache
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)->withHeaders([
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "Expires" => "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT",
            "Cache-Control" => "no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0, private",
        ]);
    }
}
```

Source: [Attaching Headers To Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses)

Comment: The cache-control options are redundant and superfluous, and some contradict.  I.e. no-store says not to store the resource in any cache, but then you have no-cache which means it's okay to cache but the resource has to be revalidated with the origin.  And then you have must-revalidate, which is implied by no-cache in this case since the max-age is 0 (the resource is never fresh).  And then you have max-age=0... but the no-store says not to cache at all.  And then you have private, which means it's okay to store the resource in private caches like the browser... but no-cache contradicts.

Comment: After 2 years it still works for me as expected.