# how to create middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have created the project which has login page **login.blade.php** which has only **Regno** to login-in.
once it login is the success it will redirect to **home.blade.php** and it followed by 4 more pages when clicking of next button in each page 
**page2.blade.php**,**page3.blade.php**,**page4.blade.php**,**page5.blade.php** and finally, it should redirect to **login** page itself. The problem is the browser back button should not allow it to go back to the previous page.

can anyone suggest me how to create middleware for this?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The browser's back button is not controlled by the server, where Laravel runs. There is no way for you to block it or interact with it in any way inside your PHP code.

What you can do is send `XMLHHTTPRequest` (XHR) with JavaScript. They ensure that on a button click you will stay on the same page in the browser and then your JS-code can read the server response (your rendered page templates) and replace the current content with the one from that response. You can read more on this when you google for AJAX, e.g. this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Comment: is that possible to display it in full screen??

Comment: You mean opening your browser in full screen or replace the whole page? You might want to keep the js-part that is being executed, e.g. by wrapping your page body in a div that is being replaced with the new data, and you might have to make sure that the new button will be bound to the event, but I think it should be possible. In any case this is not a question related to php or laravel. If you try it out and ask specific questions with js, jquery, ajax as tags you might get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Read this thing. I once implemented in the same way. By setting cache control in response header.
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821808/10239067

Comment: sorry i didn't get, in that cache everything is there