# Laravel: getting the session id of another user in a load balanced environment

Tags: php, laravel

here is my situation, I have 8 load balanced nginx server with ha proxy as the load balancer. We are currently facing an issue, for example, user B is currently logged into the system, browsing through pages doing normal stuff. Then user A comes to the system, he logs in, but the response he get has the session id of user B, thereby getting user b as the authorized user in user A’s screen. These are the solutions we implemented so far:

- sticky sessions for ha proxy
- end session when user closes browser
- regenerate session everytime user logs in

Hopefully you can share other solutions to our problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your solutions are good also you can user small time for session expiry

Comment: What method do you currently have as your SESSION_DRIVER? I would guess it's file with the issues you face? Another solution would be to change the session driver to something like Redis or memcached for fast cached based session. Or if you would like, you can even change it to Database, although this will put more load on your DB server and can be slower. I suggest using something like Redis that is held on it's own instance or at least not on the load balanced nginx servers. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#configuration

Comment: Our session driver is redis. This only randomly happens. Based on my research in this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-auth-retrieve-wrongunexpected-user something to do with micro caching but not sure what this is.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821563/laravel-5-5-how-to-set-cache-control-http-header-globally and https://itnext.io/laravel-the-hidden-setcacheheaders-middleware-4cd594ba462f

Comment: Ok, will check it out. Thanks!