# How to remove Azure default Cache-Control in NGINX and replace it with must-revalidate

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I'm hosting a PHP 8, laravel 8.x, application on Azure via an App Service. Inside of my NGINX configuration, I specify the following:

```
add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate";
```

Now, this shows in the response headers but Azure appears to be overloading this with its own that looks to be taking presedence in the browser:

[image]

My NGINX configuration does not contain this "no-cache, private" header. Due to this being a SPA application, the javascript changes are causing people to need to re-validate via a cache-clear on each individual page.

Is there some way in Azure I can stop this and keep it as only "no-cache, must-revalidate"?

Update: I have since changed it to `add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";` but the `no-cache, private` seems to still be taking presedence.

[image: New headers]

Further Update, I now have this inside my NGINX:

```
# Cache control
add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
add_header Pragma "no-cache";
add_header Expires "0";

# Further Cache Control
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;

# Proxy Cache Control
proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1;
```

And my browser is still caching and I can still see `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` above my headers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821563/laravel-5-how-to-set-cache-control-http-header-globally

Comment: @Olivier thanks for your response but this is effecting static files as well. For some reason, anything in the `/public/js` directory is also obtaining a `no-cache, private`

Comment: Can you try adding something like `proxy_hide_header Cache-Control` before adding yours? I like to use this when handling headers with Nginx: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/ which has among other things a `more_clear_headers` method